# how to generate MEX from package function in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, mex, matlab-coder

I have the following directory structure:

```
main
   +model
      run.m
   +options
      opt.m
main.m
```

and so forth.

I have a function under `+model` directory called `run` that depends on some functions in the `+options` directory, such that my `main.m` script under directory `main` calls `model.run()` and the function `run` calls some `options.opt()`.

I want to generate a MEX file of `model.run()`, so I run the `coder` from MATLAB command prompt, and on the first screen, where I enter the function name to generate code `model.run`, the coder simply displays the error:

> This file is shadowed by C:\....\+model\run.m

I already tried adding the `main` directory to the path, but it didn't work.

- Is it possible to compile a MEX for `model.run()` in this scenario?

MATLAB version: '9.4.0.813654 (R2018a)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generating code directly from a function in a package is unfortunately not supported in MATLAB Coder as of MATLAB R2019a. We've made an internal note of your request so we can look at lifting that limitation in the future.

The workaround right now is to add a wrapper function outside of a package that calls `model.run` and use that as your entry-point function with Coder. You could then move the resulting MEX file to your `+model` directory so that `model.run` calls the generated MEX in the rest of your code.